# Can't get a hash of a file while downloading in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, hash, stream

I'm looking for the simplest way to download a file and save it to disk, and get a md5 hash of the file. Is there a way to do it using piping, so I get the md5 while it's downloading rather than at the end?

If I do it like below, the file on disk doesn't contain the actual contents of the url, it contains an md5 but I don't know where that md5 comes from.

```
var md5 = crypto.createHash('md5').setEncoding('hex')
got.stream(url)
  .pipe(md5)
  .pipe(fs.createWriteStream(file))
  .on('finish', function() {
    console.log(md5.read())
  })
```

But this code below works (it removes the `fs.createWriteStream` line) and prints the correct md5 of the file, however it doesn't save the file to disk. How can I make the above work as expected?

```
var md5 = crypto.createHash('md5').setEncoding('hex')
got.stream(url)
  .pipe(md5)
  .on('finish', function() {
    console.log(md5.read())
  })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have to fork your stream. One part of the stream will go to your `createWriteStream` and the other part will go to the `md5`. The following code should solve your problem :

```
var md5 = crypto.createHash('md5').setEncoding('hex');
var urlStream = got.stream(url);

urlStream.pipe(fs.createWriteStream(file));

urlStream.pipe(md5)
  .on('finish', function() {
    console.log(md5.read())
  });
```

Comment: Does `urlStream` download the `url` once or twice in this case, since it's being used in 2 places?